# How to iterate first ten items from the container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I want to print only first 10 inserted items while leaving the rest behind. What code do i have to use (instead of using `myset.end()` ) to print only first 10 integers instead of printing every single integer.

```
int main ()
{
std::set<int> myset;
std::set<int>::iterator it;

// set some initial values:
for (int i=1; i<=20; ++i) 
    myset.insert(i*10);    

std::cout << "myset contains:";
for (it=myset.begin(); it!=myset.end(); ++it)
std::cout << *it << ' ';
std::cout << "\n\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::set`'s iterators are not ransom-access, so the easiest way is to set up a counter and break when it reaches 10.

Comment: For some other containers, like `std:vector`, you can use `begin() + 10` as the end condition for stopping after 10 elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might use `std::next` as follow:

```
const auto begin = myset.begin();
const auto end = myset.size() < 10 ? myset.end() : std::next(begin, 10);
for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Why `const auto begin` and not simply `for (auto it = myset.begin(), ...)` ?

Comment: To avoid to repeat `myset.begin()` also used as argument in `std::next`.

Comment: Also there seems to be a small loss of generality since `std::next` would consume an `input_iterator`? But the question asks about a container, so it still fits.

Comment: If you are 100% sure `myset` has at least 10 elements, I would write simply `for (auto it=myset.begin(), end=std::next(it,10); it!=end; ++it)`; it's more concise. Possibly preceded by `assert(myset.size() >= 10);`.

Comment: Also, I like this solution, however, I would note that it might be inefficient, since it effectively iterates over the elements of the set two times (while other solutions with counters does not).

Comment: @DanielLangr: but they do 2 checks at each iteration. I expect same timing for all provided solutions.

Comment: @Jarod42 Checking an integer in register can be much faster than traversing BST, which generally may cause a lot of cache misses. Of course, there would likely be no observable difference in OP's simple code, however, in practical applications I believe there might be (and one needs to profile of course to prove it).

Comment: @Jarod42 I just run the following benchmark: https://wandbox.org/permlink/IOvnDSa7w0fsggMJ on a standalone machine (Xeon Broadwell server processor, g++ 5.4.0, `-O3`). With the 1st loop version, it took **41ms**, with the 2nd version **26ms**. The difference is significant.

Comment: @DanielLangr: If you're not sure `myset` has 10 elements, you could just make that `size` part of the `std::next` call and work equivalently, e.g. `end=std::next(it,std::min(10,myset.size()))`. Starts to get a little more complex, so you could move the `min` calculation outside the loop for clarity. I'd never trust the codebase enough to say I was 100% sure `myset` had at least 10 elements unless it was initialized with constant data in the same function and not modified since; if < 10 elements is an error, I'd prefer to check it and abort/raise exception rather than risk undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Indeed, `++it` takes longer than one comparison, so version with `next` is 2 times slower: [Benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/2Wb4xoEpNIoOfr1Md4XTMAxd0_A) (as we do traversal twice).

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep a `count` variable and break the loop as soon as it reaches 10 or you reach `myset.end()`.

```
int main ()
{
    std::set<int> myset;
    std::set<int>::iterator it;

    // set some initial values:
    for (int i=1; i<=20; ++i) 
        myset.insert(i*10);    

    int count = 0;
    std::cout << "myset contains:";
    for (it=myset.begin(); count < 10 && it!=myset.end(); ++it, ++count)
        std::cout << *it << ' ';

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
int nCount = 0;
for (it=myset.begin(); nCount<10 && it!=myset.end(); ++nCount, ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << ' ';        
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using post-increment when you don't rely on the delayed increment is a bad idea in C++; it means creating unnecessary copies instead of performing purely in-place increments for all but primitive types (and iterators are not primitive). Make it `++it`, not `it++`.

Comment: Changed it, seems someone already had the same answer. Thanks.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Either you're misreading/misapplying the note, or there was an edit between the version of this answer I commented on and the present version that didn't persist in the history. The concern about `++` and iterators from that note relates to using it on an r-value, not to `++` and iterators in general. `++it` is the idiomatic way to advance *any* iterator a single step; [allowing increment is a contractual requirement of all iterator categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories). `it` is an l-value, and incrementing is perfectly fine.

Comment: Given that `std::next` would typically be implemented in terms of `std::advance`, which is defined to use increment for iterators which don't meet the requirements of `RandomAccessIterator`, it would be ridiculous if increment wasn't guaranteed to work but `std::next` was.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I was referring to the general use of ++ vs std::next for iterators. Thanks for clarifying r-value specifics.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: K. To be clear, if you were suggesting they do `it = std::next(it)` as opposed to `++it`, that's actually going to have the same inefficiencies as `it++`; the argument to `std::next` is received by value (intentionally; it doesn't modify the caller's argument) so the iterator is copied, and a new iterator based on that copy is returned. That's almost the same problem `it++` has (it doesn't reassign `it`, but it must create and destroy a temporary copy of `it`'s original value, while incrementing `it` in place). `std::advance(it,1)` avoids that cost, but adds nothing over `++it`.

Comment: The only real use cases for `std::next` are when you *want* a newly created iterator offset from an existing one. `it++` is even less useful, since it's only "useful" when you want to *use* the old value, but increment for all future operations, as a one-liner, but while `do_something(*it++);` is kinda pretty and concise, it's guaranteed to perform worse than the (almost) equivalent `do_something(*it); ++it;` (the only code logic distinctions between the two approaches involve rare and complicated uses of threads and/or reentrant code).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I gotcha, thank you for explaining this